# Cloud sql partial replication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I went through https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/replication to create partial replica only with 5-6 tables from a DB with >50 tables. Existing questions provide partial explanation - they either say its not possible or that's not what replica's are for.

I think this is a good standard use case. Each read application can't be provided access to master DB especially when they are third parties. One way is to write an application to export partial data to third parties but I am hoping for GCP based solution.

**Looking for partial DB replication:**

1. I don't want to provide external access on main instance just for a few tables in DB.
2. I only need data from 5 tables and not the entire DB. Hence, don't want to pay for the entire DB replica.

This is more of possibility/documentation question.

Edit:
Version of my instance: POSTGRES_14_7.R20230530.01_04

Comment: Are you using Cloud SQL `Microsoft SQL Server`?

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am using postgres, version: POSTGRES_14_7.R20230530.01_04.
Updated my post.